# How to use devise with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm using Cassandra as the database and want to use Devise

Does Devise support Cassandra as the database? I looked around but did not find any information related to Devise-Cassandra on the wiki or anywhere else.

Is there third party plugins supporting it or other gem for authentication as devise?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, I have never heard of such thing.

Actually I suggest you keep your users in a more traditional database and use cassandra only for the most intensive I/O data.

Cassandra wasn't made to substitute other databases nor to be user with ORM (that's actually written in its official webpage)